# Hibernate join inheritance wrong type on query result

Tags: spring, hibernate, inheritance

I'm new to spring/hibernate. I have written a webservice that should return full objects and sometimes reduced objects. For example, I have a `Member` class that inherits from a `MemberBase` class :

```
...

**
 * MemberBase
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "MemberBase")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idgen", sequenceName = "seq_Member")
public class MemberBase extends BasePojo {

    @Column(name = "alias")
    private String alias = null;
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName = null;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender = null;

    @Transient
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "creator")
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=OutingBase.class)
    private Set<OutingBase> outings = null;

...
}
```

and Member :

```
...

/**
 * Member
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "Member")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idgen", sequenceName = "seq_Member")
public class Member extends MemberBase {


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MaritalStatus maritalStatus = null;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate birthDate = null;

    private String locationName = null;

    private DateTime lastConnexion = null;

    private String description = null;

    private String videoMoodUrl = null;

    private String mood = null;

    private Boolean canCertify = null;

    private String fid = null;
    ...
}
```

In my controller I use hibernate to get a list of member base :

```
public ResponseEntity<List<MemberBase>> membersGet() {
        Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<MemberBase> personList = session.createQuery("FROM " + MemberBase.class.getName(), MemberBase.class)
                .getResultList();

        session.close();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<MemberBase>>(personList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

And here is how I create my session factory :

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(BasePojo.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(MemberBase.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Member.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(OutingBase.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Outing.class);

            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

**My problem is that when I call `membersGet()`, I retrieve a `List<Member>` and not a list of `List<MemberBase>`. There is no crash, but my serialised Json contains too much fields. I implemented this inheritance to avoid getting all the `Member`'s fields. What did I do wrong ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend using the `JsonIgnore` anotation from FasterXML Jackson.

As the name indicates the anotation will result in ignoring the property when parsing the object.

e. g.

```
@JsonIgnore    
private String locationName = null;
```

EDIT:

Use `JsonView`to specify for which view the property should be shown/parsed.
e. g.

```
public class JsonView {
    public static class Base {
    } 
    public static class Extended extends Base {
    }
}

@JsonView(JsonView.Extended.class)
private String locationName = null;

@JsonView(JsonView.Base.class)
private String alias = null;
```

And when you map it you can specify the view you want.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String result = mapper
      .writerWithView(JsonView.Extended.class)
      .writeValueAsString(member);
```

see here: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Comment: ok, but in some case I need to get the full `Member` so this can't be the solution :)

Comment: thanks for the edit, now I know JsonView and read the documentation in the link you provided. I did not use a mapper but the annotation on my spring interface like this :
    
`    @JsonView(JsonView.Extended.class)
    @RequestMapping("/items/internal/{id}")
    public Item getItemInternal(@PathVariable int id) {
        return ItemManager.getById(id);
    }
`

Comment: Glad that I could help you.